# how to detect received push notification when app is closed

Tags: parse-platform, ios8, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

Is there anybody knows that if I received a push notification when my app is fully closed, but then I go back to open the app how can I detect this received notification and make certain changes pertain to this notification?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way:

Just detect the Badge numbers, and set it as a user default in app delegate.

In other view controllers, you can perform stuffs depends on the badge numbers, which you can track from NSUserDefault.